# KOValidation get observable value, $index(), $data etc. in the error message

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following JS object:

```
var TournamentPlayer = function (PlayerName, Handicap, Nationality) {
    var self = this;

    self.PlayerName = ko.observable(PlayerName).extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Player No. ' + $index() + ' is required.' // How to get $index() here?
        }
    });
    self.Handicap = ko.observable(Handicap);
    self.Nationality = ko.observable(Nationality);
}
```

I need to capture details of four players where `PlayerName` is required, I am using the following code to add empty `TournamentPlayer` objects in the parent JS object:

```
self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
```

I want to get `KO` data like the `observable` value, `$index()`, `$data()` etc in the `KOValidation` `extend` function, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to do this by coding the index into the view models, thus making it unit testable:

```
var TournamentPlayer = function (PlayerName, Handicap, Nationality, GetNr) {
    var self = this;
    self.PlayerName = ko.observable(PlayerName).extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Player No. ' + GetNr(self) + ' is required.'
        }
    });
}
```

Then instantiate them like this:

```
var Root = function() {
    self.TournamentPlayers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.GetNr = function(p) { return self.TournamentPlayers.indexOf(p); };
    self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, '', self.GetNr));
    // etc.
}
```

But this does not work correctly, because `GetNr(self)` is called once, upon *constructing* the Player, before it has been `push`ed into the array (thus they all get a nr of `-1`).

Unfortunately, the `message` of an extension cannot be (AFAICT) an observable. There is [formatting for custom rules](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Override-Error-Messages), where I guess you could "inherit" from the default `required` rule and give it formattable messages.

With all that, I'm afraid the best way to do what you want is render custom messages in your markup, something like this:

```js
var TournamentPlayer = function (PlayerName, Handicap, Nationality) {
  var self = this;
  self.PlayerName = ko.observable(PlayerName).extend({
    required: {
      message: 'Player Name is required.'
    }
  });
}

var Root = function() {
  self.TournamentPlayers = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.GetNr = function(p) { return self.TournamentPlayers.indexOf(p); };
  self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
  self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
  self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
  self.TournamentPlayers.push(new TournamentPlayer('', 0, ''));
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```css
.validationMessage { display: none; }
.customValidationMessage { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: TournamentPlayers">
  <li>
    Player Name: 
    <input data-bind="textInput: PlayerName">
    <span class="customValidationMessage" data-bind="visible: !PlayerName.isValid()">
      Player 
      <span data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></span>
      is required.
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Not pretty, and I welcome competing answers, but best I could come up with so far...

Comment: I am getting a blank object in the `p` parameter in the `GetNr` function